# C# String Contains vs String Replace speed testing - questions arise

Tags: c#, string

Take these scenarios:

```
if (_items.Contains("M"))
{
    _items.Replace("M", "N");
}

_items.Replace("M", "N");
```

This is a table of the outcome using DotNet Benchmarking when doing a test with a random string (with a seed) of differing character lengths

[image]

These results I don't understand.

Why does it not allocate any memory until 25 characters, why is it faster to look into the string first to see if a character exists before replacing it on a string of less than 25 characters, but not when it is 25 or more?

I was trying see which was the better use case, and thought I would run a quick test - expecting a rather straight forward answer - don't look into the string twice, once to see if it is there, then again to remove it - but for short strings it appears it is better to look and see first?

Comment: How many iterations in your test?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I tried the same with some additional tests; my results are below. Sorry, no answers - just more questions. :)

It definitely looks like `WithContains` is the winner. With smaller string lengths, the difference it inconsequential, but with larger strings, the `WithContains` starts to pull away.

The `WithRegex` results also surprise me.

| Method | N | StringLength | Mean | Error | StdDev | Rank | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WithoutContains | 100 | 10 | 187.8 ns | 3.82 ns | 3.19 ns | 1 | 0.0265 | 112 B |
| WithContains | 100 | 10 | 188.8 ns | 3.40 ns | 2.84 ns | 1 | 0.0262 | 112 B |
| WithCharArray | 100 | 10 | 200.9 ns | 3.84 ns | 3.95 ns | 2 | 0.0572 | 240 B |
| WithRegex | 100 | 10 | 251.5 ns | 3.04 ns | 2.70 ns | 3 | 0.0262 | 112 B |
| WithContains | 100 | 20 | 366.3 ns | 7.19 ns | 17.10 ns | 4 | 0.0386 | 163 B |
| WithoutContains | 100 | 20 | 405.2 ns | 7.69 ns | 7.90 ns | 5 | 0.0386 | 163 B |
| WithCharArray | 100 | 20 | 425.1 ns | 8.52 ns | 8.36 ns | 6 | 0.0763 | 320 B |
| WithRegex | 100 | 20 | 493.9 ns | 7.69 ns | 6.82 ns | 7 | 0.0381 | 163 B |
| WithContains | 100 | 30 | 538.2 ns | 8.80 ns | 7.35 ns | 8 | 0.0563 | 237 B |
| WithoutContains | 100 | 30 | 596.5 ns | 11.96 ns | 26.00 ns | 9 | 0.0563 | 237 B |
| WithCharArray | 100 | 30 | 614.8 ns | 12.26 ns | 11.47 ns | 10 | 0.1049 | 440 B |
| WithRegex | 100 | 30 | 708.7 ns | 11.90 ns | 11.13 ns | 11 | 0.0563 | 237 B |
| WithContains | 100 | 50 | 839.2 ns | 8.90 ns | 8.33 ns | 12 | 0.0868 | 366 B |
| WithoutContains | 100 | 50 | 922.7 ns | 10.11 ns | 9.46 ns | 13 | 0.0868 | 366 B |
| WithCharArray | 100 | 50 | 992.6 ns | 19.04 ns | 21.92 ns | 14 | 0.1526 | 640 B |
| WithRegex | 100 | 50 | 1,101.0 ns | 12.67 ns | 11.23 ns | 15 | 0.0858 | 366 B |
| WithContains | 100 | 100 | 1,607.4 ns | 29.12 ns | 25.82 ns | 16 | 0.1583 | 668 B |
| WithCharArray | 100 | 100 | 1,931.5 ns | 37.57 ns | 33.31 ns | 17 | 0.2670 | 1120 B |
| WithoutContains | 100 | 100 | 1,970.1 ns | 39.48 ns | 49.92 ns | 17 | 0.1583 | 668 B |
| WithRegex | 100 | 100 | 2,064.0 ns | 40.26 ns | 53.75 ns | 18 | 0.1564 | 668 B |

My benchmark code:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Order;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Experiments
{
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    [Orderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
    [RankColumn]
    public class StringContainsReplace
    {
        [Params(100)]
        public int N;

        [Params(10, 20, 30, 50, 100)]
        public int StringLength;

        [Benchmark]
        public string WithContains()
        {
            string x = CreateString(StringLength);
            if (x.Contains("M"))
            {
                x = x.Replace("M", "N");
            }
            return x;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public string WithoutContains()
        {
            return CreateString(StringLength).Replace("M", "N");
        }

        private readonly static Regex regex = new Regex("M");

        [Benchmark]
        public string WithRegex()
        {
            return regex.Replace(CreateString(StringLength), "N");
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public string WithCharArray()
        {
            return new string(Replace(CreateString(StringLength)).ToArray());
        }

        private IEnumerable<char> Replace(string input)
        {
            ReadOnlySpan<char> ros = input.ToCharArray();
            for (int c = 0; c < ros.Length; c++)
            {
                yield return ros[c] == 'M' ? 'N' : ros[c];
            }
        }

        private readonly static Random random = new Random(17);

        private static string CreateString(int len)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[len];

            for (int c = 0; c < chars.Length; c++)
            {
                chars[c] = Convert.ToChar(random.Next(0, 26) + 65);
            }

            return new string(chars);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, when I copied your code, it wouldn't run the ReadOnly<span> coming back with an instance error.  My test only has 1 iteration, I thought Benchmark itself ran the test a few times to get an average time, so didn't put it in a loop.

Comment: In your tests, is an “M” always present in the string? Maybe Contains wins because sometimes it doesn’t find an “M.”

Comment: It is not always present, and the more characters you add, the more chance there is of an M being present.